# Cannot Save Recorded WebRTC Video/Audio to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, webrtc

I'm using RecordRTC.js to generate a .webm blob on the client side - this is all working as expected. I then need to save this .Webm file to Amazon S3.

I'm currently getting a "no element found" message in the console as populating a file field with the blob is not allowed due to security - So what is the proper practice for sending the blob?

A corrupt .webm file is being saved on my S3 account, so the application is able to connect to S3.

Here's my JavaScript that attempts to send the .webm file:

```
/**
 * S3 CORS
 */
uploading = false;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function uploadFile() {

    var fd = new FormData();
    var key = 'webup-' + (new Date).getTime() + '-' + 'webcam.webm'

    fd.append('key', key);
    fd.append('acl', 'private');
    fd.append('Content-Type', 'video/webm');
    fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', 'access-id');
    fd.append('policy', 'policy-str');
    fd.append('signature', 'signature-str');

    fd.append('file', blob);  // blob = video.src (the generated webm file)

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

    xhr.open('POST', 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/', true);
    xhr.send(fd);

    uploading = true;
}

function uploadProgress(evt) { }
function uploadComplete(evt) { alert('Upload Complete'); }
function uploadFailed(evt)   { alert('Upload Failed'); }
function uploadCanceled(evt) { alert('Upload Canceled') }

/** 
 * ready()
 */
 $(document).ready(function(){
     saveRecording.disabled = true;
     $("#save-recording").click(function(){
        uploadFile();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [recordly.io](https://github.com/rjmackay/recordly.io); check file [iohandler.js#L24](https://github.com/rjmackay/recordly.io/blob/master/iohandler.js#L24). It is reading recorded-blobs as Data-URLs; and pushing resulting DataURLs to nodejs server using socket.io messaging; however you can easily choose HTTP-POST mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This got me thinking - my application is written in Python, so would it be viable to set up a separate NodeJS server to handle the webcam video/audio uploads?

Comment: Simply [get DataURL](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC#how-to-get-dataurl) and it will work with your Python project as well. Then you don't need to setup nodejs externally.